# unix command svn log to get just the files information

Tags: svn, unix, awk, cut

Just need the directory name and files changes information in svn log

This is my svn log

```
svn log -v http://test/svn/Demo/branches/HelloWorld/Batch/ --limit 2

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r133 | testuser1 | 2013-04-02 18:22:28 -0400 (Tue, 02 Apr 2013) | 3 lines
Changed paths:
M /branches/HelloWorld/Batch/test.java

DEMO-13
Testing to lock 

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r132 | testuser2 | 2013-04-02 18:20:40 -0400 (Tue, 02 Apr 2013) | 3 lines
Changed paths:
M /branches/HelloWorld/Batch/test.java

DEMO-1
Testing to lock
```

Desired output:

```
Batch/test.java
Batch/test.java
```

My script:

```
 svn log -v http://test/svn/Demo/branches/HelloWorld/Batch/ --limit 2 | awk '$1~/^[AMD]$/{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $i}'
```

Script output:

```
/branches/HelloWorld/Batch/test.java
/branches/HelloWorld/Batch/test.java
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
what ever process you are running | awk -v FS="[/ ]" '$1~/^[AMD]$/{print $(NF-1)"/"$NF}'
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat svn.log
svn log -v http://test/svn/Demo/branches/HelloWorld/Batch/ --limit 2

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r133 | testuser1 | 2013-04-02 18:22:28 -0400 (Tue, 02 Apr 2013) | 3 lines
Changed paths:
M /branches/HelloWorld/Batch/test.java

DEMO-13
Testing to lock

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r132 | testuser2 | 2013-04-02 18:20:40 -0400 (Tue, 02 Apr 2013) | 3 lines
Changed paths:
M /branches/HelloWorld/Batch/test.java

DEMO-1
Testing to lock
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v FS="[/ ]" '$1~/^[AMD]$/{print $(NF-1)"/"$NF}' svn.log
Batch/test.java
Batch/test.java
```

Comment: Make sure that you are piping it correctly. I ran it against the log file directly and gives the output you need.

Comment: `svn log -v http://test/svn/Demo/branches/HelloWorld/Batch/ --limit 2 | awk -v FS="[/ ]" '$1~/^[AMD]$/{print $(NF-1)"/"$NF}'` -- this looks right ?

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it just set the field separator to be either a space or a forward slash and print the last two fields on the matching lines:

```
awk '$1~/^[AMD]$/{print $(NF-1),$NF}' FS=' |/' OFS='/'
```

Output would be:

```
Batch/test.java
Batch/test.java
```

Comment: Please tell me you actually piped in your `svn` command first?

Comment: `svn log -v http://test/svn/Demo/branches/HelloWorld/Batch/ --limit 2 | awk '$1~/^[AMD]$/{print $(NF-1),$NF}' FS=' |/' OFS='/'`

Comment: You have learnt how to ask a good question that shows the input, expected output, your attempt and your given output but your comments are still utterly useless. The only useful help I can give you is **try debugging** the problem. This script given works on the input you provided and is only a small modification from the script you gave in the question. Check the output of `svn log -v http://test/svn/Demo/branches/HelloWorld/Batch/ --limit 2` and make sure it is the output you expect.

Comment: sorry ...i thought you asked what i ran on my cygwin hence i copy pasted it directly.